# Fragment InstantiationException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Basically I'm getting this error:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment Archenemy: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Now I know there have been plenty of questions where the issue was they didn't have an empty constructor. I do, as you will see. My question is, what else could cause this error?

```
public class Archenemy_Activity extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public Archenemy_Activity() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.archenemy_layout, container, false);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have other excpetions in the logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `new Archenemy_Activity()` instead of `Archenemy_Activity.instantiate(.....)`

Answer (score 0):

make your constructor like this:

```
public Archenemy_Activity newInstance(){
      Archenemy_Activity fragment = new Archenemy_Activity();
      return fragment;
}
```

when instance just use `Archenemy_Activity.newInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the reason it couldn't create the class was because the class couldn't be found when trying to be instantiated. I was using the following code:

```
Arch_Fragment = Fragment.instantiate(parent, "ArchenemyFragment");
```

However I didn't include the full path to the class in that string, (it should have been "com.example.namespace.ArchenemyFragment" I replaced it with this (which automatically works out the full path), and it's been working:

```
Arch_Fragment = Fragment.instantiate(parent, ArchenemyFragment.class.getName());
```